# Javascript code fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Code seems to fail at `if(var i = 1;){` works fine if `if(var i = 1;){` and so on are removed and just `item.text("Options for your number " + i +"th $Name");` is there.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

$('#Quantity').keyup(function () {
    var textualValue = $(this).val();
    var numericValue = parseInt(textualValue, 10);

    if (!isNaN(numericValue)) {
        modifyDOMWithNumber(numericValue);
    } else {
        modifyDOMWithNumber(0);
    }
});

function modifyDOMWithNumber(number) {
    var ul = $('ul#ListToAlter').empty();
    var item;

    for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        item = $("<li>");

        if(var i = 1;){
        item.text("Options for your 1st $Name");
        }elsif(var i = 2;){
        item.text("Options for your 2nd $Name");
        }elsif(var i = 3;){
        item.text("Options for your 3rd $Name");
        }else{
        item.text("Options for your number " + i +"th $Name");
        }

        ul.append(item);
    }
}
//]]></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove the semicolon**

```
if(var i = 1){
```

**This is always true**

`=` is a assignment operator  and  `==` is a comparison operator

And **elsif** is supposed to be **else if** notice the space

Should be something like this

```
for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    item = $("<li>");

    if (i == 1) {
        item.text("Options for your 1st $Name");
    }
    else if(i == 2) {
        item.text("Options for your 2nd $Name");
    }
    else if(i == 3) {
        item.text("Options for your 3rd $Name");
    } else {
        item.text("Options for your number " + i + "th $Name");
    }

    ul.append(item);
}
```

Comment: what does `elsif` mean...?

Comment: I think he meant "else if".

Comment: The mistake is from the question posters code. Sushanth just copied it.

Comment: @user2443899.. You are welcome..  Also it is better to use `===` rather than `==` as the former is faster and more efficient

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to compare is `if (i == 1) { /* do stuff */ }`.
When using a single "=" symbol, you are ASSIGNING a value to the variable, not comparing it's value.

```
if (i == 1) { /* do stuff */ }
else if (i == 2) { /* do some other stuff */ }
else { /* if none of the above work */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

well transform from

`if (var i = 1;)`

to

`if (i == 1)`

first of all is not syntactical correct

second of all `(i = 1)` gives a value to `i` does't test it with `1`

`=`   - assignment operator

`==`  - is equal to

`===` - is exactly equal to (value and type)

Answer (score 1):

`var i = 1;` is an assignment operator (and shouldn't have the semicolon anyways). What you want is `if (i==1){` and so on for the other numbers. Try changing it and let me know if you need more help :)

When evaluating the same variable against different values, you could alternatively use a [switch statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp). So you could rewrite your code as follows:

```
switch(i)
{
    case 1:
    {
        item.text("Options for your 1st $Name");
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        item.text("Options for your 2nd $Name");
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        item.text("Options for your 3rd $Name");
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        item.text("Options for your number " + i +"th $Name");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if (var i==1)
```

and not i=1 as in your case.

you need to compare values and requires atleast 2= signs